# Why is the inductor crossed by null current in this simple circuit problem?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, thevenin

I'm new to EE. While doing some exercises, I encountered a problem where I have the following sine wave circuit, where:

e(t)=10cos(1000t)[V], a(t)=4sqrt(2)cos(1000t+pi/4)[A], C=1[mF], L=2[mH]

[image]

The problem asks me to find the Thevenin equivalent in the endpoints AB.

First of all, I found the impedance of the capacitor and inductor, then I found the voltage between the endpoints AB. Now, the textbook's solution says that in this condition, the inductor is crossed by null current. Can someone explain why is it that?

Comment: Where would the current be going if there was current?

Comment: I'm really new to circuits, so I might need a tip

Comment: There is no load